# Drop empty groups or stack it in bar plot

Tags: python, seaborn

This is my code

```
test = clusters[['Cluster', 'Titularidad_Centro' ,'Freq']].groupby(['Cluster', 'Titularidad_Centro'], as_index = True).sum()
test = test.sort_values(['Cluster','Freq'], ascending=[True, False])
test['Porcentaje'] = test.groupby(['Cluster']).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum()))
test = test.groupby(['Cluster']).head(1).reset_index()
sns.factorplot(x='Cluster', y='Porcentaje', data=test, hue='Titularidad_Centro', kind='bar',  palette="husl", aspect=20/8.27)
plt.show()
```

and I obtain this plot

[image]

but I need one bar by cluster, so I need drop empty categories or stack the groups since I only have one category by cluster.

Comment: Don't use seaborn if you don't need/want the kind of output it offers. Simply draw a barplot using `matplotlib` and color according to "Titularidad_Centro".

Comment: My problem is that I'm not going to know the number of categories that I'm going to have in Titularidad_Centro, and from what I have seen, the coloring in matplotlib is done with a manual mapping of the colors with the categories. I haven't seen how to do it with a third variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `dodge=False`. But it looks like you're using an old version and may need to update first.